# formatting columns using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function below that reads from a csv (sample included below also)

Function:

```
def logic_one(grades):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(grades)
    del df1['Student ID']
    df2 = df1.mean()
    df2.columns = ['Questions', 'Mean']
    print(df2)
```

CSV Sample:

```
Student ID,Question 1,Question 2,Question 3,Question 4,Question 5,Question 6
205842,6.5,6.5,9.5,5.5,3.5,9.5
280642,8.5,9.5,3.5,9.5,4,9.5
289179,7,9.5,9,9.5,7,4
```

It is currently returning the following:

```
Question 1 6.62
Question 2 6.74
Question 3 6.55
Question 4 6.11
Question 5 6.69
Question 6 6.74
dtype: float64
```

However I want it to return with a heading called 'Mean' above column 2. I thought line 5 of my function would do this, however it isn't, does anyone have any ideas on why I am wrong?

Also if you have any feedback on how to remove the 'dtype: float64' line that would also be helpful.

Comment: `mean()` returns a Series, if you want to see column headers, convert the result to a DataFrame. `df.drop('Student ID', axis=1).mean().reset_index(name='Mean')`

Comment: could you check ur mean values ... question 1 should be 7.33 not 6.62

Answer (score 0):

As @cs95 mentioned, `mean()` returns a Series and you want to convert that to a DataFrame.

You can use [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) to do that conversion and you can name the column at the time of that conversion.

```
df2 = df1.mean().to_frame(name='Mean')
```